# Keep a progress bar on top. Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, progress

Okay so I was just wondering if there is a way to have a progress bar on the top as the script is running to tell the user that x% of the process has been completed. Also is there a command that is built into the OS that would let me use a progress bar or would i have to design that as well in code?

Comment: see it http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32651/how-to-show-the-percentage-progress-of-script-execution-in-unix

Comment: Can you be more specific with the question?  Your phrasing implies that you might want the progress to be visible as the script is running **in the background**.  That's impossible with traditional terminals, though you might be able to hack together a screen or tmux status line that does what you want.  Or are you trying to throw up a GUI program with a progress bar?  That's possible via script bindings, but not from bash.  Consider things like PyGtk.

Answer (score 1):

Include in your script a percentage tracker, but will consume more resources...

For example if you are copying a bunch of files:

`
foreach $y (@files) {

```
$countline++;
$total = 1000;
$lastcount = $currentcount
$currentcount = $countline / $total

if ( $lastcount > $currentcount ) {
    $progress_display == 1
    $currentcount

    if ($progress_display == 1) {
            print ".";
    }
```

}
print "\n";
`

Answer (score 1):

There is `zenity`, a GTK application with GUI elements for scripts. It has a progress bar and much more.

The package `dialog` provides several UI elements for shell scripting. One of them is a `gauge`, a progress bar. Debian maintains a simplified version of `dialog` called `whiptail`.

There is also an X version of `dialog`: `Xdialog`, but I have never seen it myself.